# Unity 5. Not saving scene before new scene opens

Tags: unity-game-engine

Add this code to an Editor Window script, add an object through script then try to create a new scene. Why does unity not ask to save the scene before opening a new one?

```
 Event e = Event.current;
         switch (e.type)
         {
             case EventType.keyDown:
                 {
                     if (e.keyCode == KeyCode.Escape)
                     {
                         GameObject b = new GameObject();
                         b.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
                     }
                     e.Use();    
                 }
                 break;
         }
```

Comment: Can't test here, but you probable need to tell Unity your scene has actually changed using EditorUtility.SetDirty(someObject);

Comment: Tried it man and it still didn't work. Will be playing with this option though now to see if anything can come from it. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this helps but regarding the dirty bit in Unity 5

You have to:

```
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
```

at the top of your code.  Then use:

```
EditorSceneManager.MarkAllScenesDirty(); //or mark individual scenes as dirty
```

Absolutely necessary if you have custom editor scripts dynamically instantiating game objects.  (I had one creating a tile based map.  Looked great in the editor.  I would save scene and play the game.  It was gone...)

I can't take full credit for the find, however and old unity 4 post pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/336751/is-editorutilitysetdirty-restricted-to-prefabs-or.html

This boy's a genius. How on earth are we supposed to find out that shit like this changes when we update?

[EditorApplication.MarkSceneDirty](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication.MarkSceneDirty.html)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This link may answer the question, but you should include the most important details into your answer, because any link may go obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

after creating the object, (or doing anything to an object in the scene) you need to call `EditorUtility.SetDirty(b);` The same goes if you change a value on a script that you wrote, you will need to mark that dirty as well for the changes to persist.

Comment: Hey, I just tried this and it's still not asking to save. I will play around with Dirty value some more though, so thanks for the idea. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe try setting the b.transform dirty? Setting dirty is the only thing that ive ever had problems with not saving correctly. Maybe try changing the position to Vector3.one setting dirty and then setting back to Vector3.zero to make it think its dirty.  Not a very good long term solution but it could work.

Comment: That didn't work either :/ This all works in Unity 4 with no problem and no need to setDirty. This is just Unity 5 I'm having the issue with. No new gameobject created via script for the editor will ask to save changes upon exit or new scene. Do you think this is a bug?

Comment: I think its a new "feature" judging by the other answer to this question, that probably is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help though man. You pointed me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
                        UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene());
```

make current scene modefied